# How to add more infomation for userDetails?

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to integrate Spring security authentication in my application. The problem I am having right now is after success login, I would like to retrieve the current user which is store in spring security context, I got the UserDetails instead of my User.

Comment: `UserDetails` is just an interface.

Comment: i agree with @PavelHoral. After you get UserDetails, you can downcast to your type.